# Fibonacci Line Search Method

Tags: programming, mathematical-optimization

I am attempting to write a code to find to bracket the minimum of a function using the `Fibonacci Line Search Method`, I believe my code is well written but I am not receiving output values, could anyone help with this issue?

```
FibonacciSearch[a0_, b0_, eps_] :=
 Module[{a = N[a0], b = N[b0], c, d, k},
 n = 4;
 k = 0;
 F[1] = 1;
 F[2] = 1;
 F[3] = 2;
 F[4] = 3;
 F[5] = 5;
 F[6] = 8;
 F[7] = 13;
 F[8] = 21;
 F[9] = 34;
 F[10] = 55;
  While[(b[k] - a[k]) > eps,
   c[k_] := a[k] + (b[k] - a[k]) (1 - (F[n - k + 1])/(F[n - k + 2]));
   d[k_] := a[k] + (b[k] - a[k]) ((F[n - k + 1])/(F[n - k + 2]));
If[f[c[k_]] <= f[d[k_]],
    a[k + 1] = a[k];
    b[k + 1] = d[k];
    k = k + 1;,

    a[k + 1] = c[k];
    b[k + 1] = b[k];
    k = k + 1;
Print["f[", ToString[PaddedForm[{k, a[k], b[k]}, {7, 6}]], "]"]]]]
```

Example function to be evaluated:

```
 f[x_] := x^2 + 4*Cos[x]
```

Also, any tips to aide in my programming learning process will be appreciated.

Comment: Aren't `a` and `b` two numbers? If yes, `a[k]` and `b[k]` are wrong!

Comment: Also, my guess is `Print` should be done before `k = k + 1`. Am I right?

Answer (score 4):

Your code has three major flaws:

1. Since `a`, `b` , `c` , `d` are
       numbers you cannot pass the step `k` to them. This syntax is for
       functions.
2. `Print[k]` should be used before changing the "the number of iterations" (`k=k+1`) .
3. Your code does not allow enough iterations to bracket the minimum
   (`n` is small).

You may also use internal `Fibonacci` function, instead of manually enter
values for `F`.

```
f[x_] := x^2 + 4*Cos[x];
FibonacciSearch[a0_, b0_, eps_] := Module[{a = N[a0], b = N[b0], n = 10}, 
k = 0;
While[(b - a) > eps,
     frac = (Fibonacci[n - k + 1])/(Fibonacci[n - k + 2]);
     c = a + (b - a) (1 - frac);
     d = a + (b - a)*frac;
       If[f[c] <= f[d], 
         b = d; k = k + 1;,
         a = c; Print[{k, PaddedForm[a, {7, 6}], PaddedForm[b, {7, 6}]}]; k = k + 1;]
 ]
];
```

Run it as:

```
FibonacciSearch[1, 2, 0.01]
(* {9, 1.893569, 1.901699} *)
```

Indeed `f[x]` has a minimum in the range $(1.893569, 1.901699)$,

[image]

Comment: I couldn't make it work, but it would be nice if we can pass `f` as a variable to the function to have `FibonacciSearch[f, a0_, b0_, eps_]`.

Comment: I used endpoints 1,2 with eps=0.05 and it came pretty close to being optimized, f[{ 5.000000,  1.750000,  1.875000}], I have a feeling it is wrong though

Comment: What's the right answer? Is `f(b)` max/min of the function?

Comment: Not exactly, I rewritting it right now, I believe it will with some minor adjustments. The program over shoots the minimuim

Comment: Here is the revision though, it still doesnt bracket the minimizer though, I ope you can see my logic though

Comment: The answer is somewhere between [1.8,2]

Comment: I guess you need to increase `n`. See the updated answer.

Comment: The revision works well

Comment: @RufusMitchell: I'm happy I could help. If you think this answered your question, please accept the answer.